# how to wait until firstResponder of text label is false in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, reloaddata, first-responder

I'm new to swift. My app uses photos people upload to the web and showing the photos in a table view.
It is reloading whenever some user uploads a new photo. 
I have a UITextField that when you press it the keyboard goes up. My problem is that it goes down whenever reloadView is happening (when a new photo arrives) 
What i'm trying to do is to check if the UITextField is first recogniser and if so I want to wait with the reload until it not first recogniser.

```
func refreshView()
{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            while (self.dataSource.writeSomethingTextLabel.isFirstResponder()) {
                //need to wait somehow for notification that it is not first responder anymore
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
}
```

So with this code the keyboard is not going down of course but the wile loop runs and everything is stuck. my question is how can I wait until the user finishes using the text label (first responder is false).
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conditionally reload `tableView` on two places: when new data arrives and when `textField` ends editing:

```
@class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var needsToReloadTableView = false;

    func reloadTableViewIfNeeded() {
        if needsToReloadTableView {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            needsToReloadTableView = false
        }
    }

    func gotNewData() {
        needsToReloadTableView = true

        if !self.textField.isFirstResponder {
            reloadTableViewIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField:UITextField) {
        reloadTableViewIfNeeded()
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 @IBAction func viewTapped(sender : AnyObject) {
       totalTextField.resignFirstResponder()
   }
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation